# Function return warning about const attribute

Tags: c, constants, warnings

I heavily reduced my real code in order to make it as compact as possible for this posting.

My questions is about the `const` attribute. When I compile this ...

```
const char tmp[] = "anything";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /* my code */
    return 0;
}

char *somefunction (char *c) {
    extern const char tmp[];
    /* my code */
    return tmp;
}
```

... I get:

> warning: return discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]

The code works fine.

The `somefunction` didn't touch the string `tmp`, so why does `return` generate this warning?

If I leave `const` away, the warning disappears.

Comment: Because the return type is `char*`and not `const char*`. Change `char *somefunction (char *c)` to `const char *somefunction (char *c)`

Comment: Worked ... many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you mark something as `const` you're telling the compiler you're not going to modify it.

You're taking a `const char *` and returning it as a `char *`.  That breaks the promise of `const` that you're giving to `tmp`.  Code that calls this function is free to modify what it returns because it doesn't return a `const` pointer.

Change `somefunction` to return a `const char *`:

```
const char *somefunction (char *c) {
    ...
```

Comment: Didn't think that far (newbie in C ... sorry) ... !
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you are returning a pointer you are giving the possibility to "edit" your data to the caller of the function. This is in contradiction with what you have done right before:

```
extern const char tmp[];
```

that's the declaration of a pointer to something which should remain constant, namely non editable.
The compiler is just warning you about this contradiction.